# Pushing a PHP app to Bluemix results in BuildpackCompileFailed

Tags: php, ibm-cloud, buildpack

I am trying to push my PHP app to Bluemix with `cf push phpinfo-jbs2 -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack.git` and I am getting a message that says `BuildpackCompileFailed` (full error below).

Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
[08:49 AM] jsloyer@Jeffs-MacBook-Pro-2 [php]>cf push phpinfo-jbs2 -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack.git
Creating app phpinfo-jbs2 in org jbsloyer@us.ibm.com / space dev as jbsloyer@us.ibm.com...
OK

Creating route phpinfo-jbs2.mybluemix.net...
OK

Binding phpinfo-jbs2.mybluemix.net to phpinfo-jbs2...
OK

Uploading phpinfo-jbs2...
Uploading app files from: /Users/jsloyer/Downloads/php
Uploading 717, 3 files
Done uploading               
OK

Starting app phpinfo-jbs2 in org jbsloyer@us.ibm.com / space dev as jbsloyer@us.ibm.com...
-----> Downloaded app package (4.0K)
Cloning into '/tmp/buildpacks/php-buildpack'...
Submodule 'compile-extensions' (https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/compile-extensions) registered for path 'compile-extensions'
Cloning into 'compile-extensions'...
Submodule path 'compile-extensions': checked out 'ce9345a9a6e7b00266194cadd18dbef37e791a7b'
It looks like you're deploying on a stack (currently set to *lucid64*) that's not supported by this buildpack.
That could be because you're using a recent buildpack release on a deprecated stack.
If you're using the buildpack installed by your CF admin, please let your admin know you saw this error message.
If you at one point specified a buildpack that's at git URL, please make sure you're pointed at a version that supports this stack.
Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed

FAILED
BuildpackCompileFailed

TIP: use 'cf logs phpinfo-jbs2 --recent' for more information
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently the company that owns development for Ubuntu (Cannonical) just announced it is dropping support for lucid 64 which is Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.  What does this mean for Cloud Foundry and the PHP buildpack?

Well nothing really but there is a couple gotcha's you should know about.

If you are pushing an app to Cloud Foundry and getting an error message like the following there is a workaround you need to do to get the PHP buildpack to work.

```
[08:49 AM] jsloyer@Jeffs-MacBook-Pro-2 [php]>cf push phpinfo-jbs2 -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack.git
.....
It looks like you're deploying on a stack (currently set to *lucid64*) that's not supported by this buildpack.
That could be because you're using a recent buildpack release on a deprecated stack.
If you're using the buildpack installed by your CF admin, please let your admin know you saw this error message.
If you at one point specified a buildpack that's at git URL, please make sure you're pointed at a version that supports this stack.
Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed

FAILED
BuildpackCompileFailed
```

What this is saying is the instance of Cloud Foundry that you are running on the default stack is an old version of Ubuntu. The PHP buildpack expects the newer version of linux. This stack is called `cflinuxfs2`, also known as `Ubuntu 14.04`.

To work around this you just need to specify the stack you want to use.

`cf push phpinfo-jbs2 -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack.git -s cflinuxfs2`

More information on this issue can be found at [Github](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack/issues/87).

Answer (score -1):

To avoid these type of issues, you can use the compatible buildpack that has been pre-installed into Bluemix.

```
cf push <appname> -b php_buildpack
```

To see all pre-installed buildpacks:

```
cf buildpacks
```